# How do i get the total sum of a 2d array?

Tags: c, arrays

How do i get the total sum of a 2D array ? `I'm trying to get the total sum of a 2D array but it doesn't seem to add all the numbers of the array together.

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "LenaArray.h" 

    int main () {

       int sum = 0;
        {  
           int my array[3][3] =
              1, 2, 3,    
              4, 5, 6,  
             7, 8, 9
        };  

       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {        
           for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {            
               printf("%d ", array[i][j]);        
           }
           printf ("\n");
       }     
       sum = sum + array;    
       printf ("total sum of the array is %d ", sum);
```

Comment: Please format your code and show where `lena` is initialized. What is the data it contains and what is the output you get? You can indent 4 spaces to make something a code block, or use  `~~~` or `\`\`\`` fences to delimit it. Thanks.

Comment: You're missing `{` at the beginning of the array initializer.

Comment: You should use `sum += array[i][j];` in the loop.

Comment: There's another typo: `{  int my array[3][3] = ...};` -> `int array[3][3] =  { ...};`

Comment: This is not C code. In fact this would not be valid in any language on earth. Please, write a complete, reproducible, valid example.

Comment: With `printf("%d ", array[i][j]);`, you're already printing the value of every element in the array....

Answer (score 2):

So many errors its hard to list them all.

```
int sum = 0; {           /// { creates a new scope for no good reason
int my array[3][3] =     /// Variable names cannot have spaces!
int array[3][3] = 1, ... /// Array Initializer begins with {
sum = sum + array;       /// Trying to add array to an int, mixing types!
```

- Your nested for loops only print the array values, they don't Sum ***anything***

---

---

Here is corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main () {

        int sum = 0;
        int array[3][3] = {
                            1, 2, 3,    
                            4, 5, 6,  
                            7, 8, 9
                          };  

       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       {        
           for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
           {            
               sum += array[i][j];
           }
       }     
       printf ("total sum of the array is %d ", sum);        
       return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize a variable sum before the for loop, and increment `sum += my_array[I][j]` inside the inner loop.

You need to give the same name for the array in each occurrence of this name and move the opening curly brace of the array after the `=` and not before the name of the array.